# openssl -- extract common name from a PEM file

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, pem

I have a X509 PEM file with content like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDaaaaaaa==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

To get its common name (CN, understood as the url where it can be used).
As the red square shows, a modern browser can read CN from a PEM file.
However, I do not find such from output of `openssl x509 --help`.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenSSL's command-line tools do not provide a way to extract just the common name from a certificate's subject distinguished name.

You have to parse the text yourself some way.

Per [OpenSSL'x `x509` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/x509.html), you can use `-subject` to get the subject's distinguished name:

> **OPTIONS**
>
> **Input, Output, and General Purpose Options**
>
> ...
>
> -subject
>
> Outputs the subject name.
>
> ...

But you want just the common name from that DN.  There's also

> -nameopt option
>
> Option which determines how the subject or issuer names are
> displayed. The option argument can be a single option or multiple
> options separated by commas. Alternatively the `-nameopt` switch may be
> used more than once to set multiple options. See the NAME OPTIONS
> section for more information.

and from that **NAME OPTIONS** section there is

> multiline
>
> A multiline format. It is equivalent esc_ctrl, esc_msb, sep_multiline, space_eq, lname and align.

Splitting the subject DN components across multiple lines makes automated parsing trivial.

Using

```
openssl x509 -in filnname.pem -noout -subject -nameopt multiline
```

will produce output like

```
subject=
    commonName          = CommonName
     .
     .
     .
    organizationName    = OrgName
    countryName         = Country
```

If you're running on Linux, you can process that text output:

```
openssl x509 -in file.pem -noout -subject -nameopt multiline |\
    grep commonName | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

If you need to handle spaces in the common name:

```
openssl x509 -in file.pem -noout -subject -nameopt multiline |\
    grep commonName | awk '{ $1=$2=""; print $3 }'
```

Unfortunately, that will replace each instance of multiple spaces in the common name with a single space.  Normally, spaces are not found in certificate common names, but they are possible.

And "CN, understood as the url where it can be used" is not correct.  The subject common name **can** be the URL, but the CN's use in validating a web site [has been deprecated for over 20 years](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1):

> Although
> the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
> Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.

[Subject alternative names are used](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.4):

> As noted, a client MUST NOT seek a match for a reference identifier
> of CN-ID if the presented identifiers include a DNS-ID, SRV-ID,
> URI-ID, or any application-specific identifier types supported by the
> client.

Browsers such as Chrome and Firefox have been ignoring subject common names when doing certificate validation for about five years now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some certs have values that are displayed by *openssl* on the same line as the *commonName*, separated by +.

I think this is dependent on how the subject common name is formed -- it seems to be possible to make the CN value a sequence of multiple subvalues.

An example of this is *emailAddress*, which can come out as `commonName=Joe Bloggs + emailAddress=joe@example.org`, even when using *-nameopt multiline*.

To get around this, my alternative is to use `openssl asn1parse` instead:

```awk
openssl asn1parse -in '/pathto/thecert.crt' |\
  awk -v FS=':' -v OFS='' '
    BEGIN          {e=0} 
    e==2           {$1="";$2="";$3="";print;exit} 
    /:commonName$/ {e++}
  '
```

The output of *openssl asn1parse* is a series of semi-structured, colon-separated rows:

```text
  330:d=3  hl=2 l=  69 cons: SET               
  332:d=4  hl=2 l=  21 cons: SEQUENCE          
  334:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
  339:d=5  hl=2 l=  14 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :Joel L. Bloggs
  355:d=4  hl=2 l=  44 cons: SEQUENCE          
  357:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :emailAddress
  368:d=5  hl=2 l=  31 prim: IA5STRING         :someemailaddress123@example.com
```

The *awk* script finds the *second* instance of the `:commonName` (the first instance would be the *Issuer* not the *Subject*), then blanks the first three fields of the following line and returns the remainder of that line.

Assuming the *asn1parse* format doesn't change, and there aren't more than two *commonName* fields in the certificate, it should hold...